# Why is the replace function not changing column text?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a program that reads a CSV file and returns True or False. I now want to use an If Statement to replace a column text with a string, but the replace function isn't working.

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_excel(r'C:/Users/bryanmccormack/Downloads/***.xlsx')
data = data.astype(str)
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ["Date Added","Track 
Item","Retailer","Retailer Item ID","TLD","UPC","Title",
                              "Manufacturer","Brand","Client Product 
Group","Category","Subcategory",
                              "Amazon Sub Category","Segment","Platform"])

excludes = ["chainsaw","pail","leaf","blower","genie", 
"straightener","backpack","iron","curling","dog","cat","wig"]

my_excludes = [set(key_word.lower().split()) for key_word in excludes]
match_titles = [e for e in df.Title if any(keywords.issubset for keywords 
in my_excludes)]

def is_match(title, excludes=excludes):
     my_excludes = [set(key_word.lower().split()) for key_word in 
     excludes]
     if any(keywords.issubset(title.lower().split()) for keywords in 
    my_excludes):
      return True
  return False
df['match_titles'] = df['Title'].apply(is_match)
result = df[df['match_titles']]['Retailer Item ID']
```

---

```
if df['match_titles'] == "True":
df['Track Items'].replace("Z-Exclude")
```

The code returns the column as True or False if the title contains a keyword I established, which is what I want, but the code following *** does not work. I want the "Track Items" column to show "Z-Exclude" if the "Match Titles" is listed as "True." Why does it not change the column text from "Track Items" to "Z-Exclude"?

Comment: If you are just trying to change the name of the column, just do `df.rename(columns={"Track Items": "Z-Exclude"}, inplace=True)`

Comment: I don't want to change the title of the column; rather, I want the text in each column, marked as True in the "Match titles", to replace the text with "Z-Exclude"

Comment: When you create the dataframe, the column is called `Track Item` but at the bottom of your script you typed `Track Items`. Typo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
df.loc[df['match_titles'] == True, 'Track Items'] = 'Z-Exclude'
```